# Failed to invoke public android.webkit.CookieManager() with no args

Tags: android, gson, runtimeexception, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-cookiemanager

I'm having this runtime exception when trying to do something like:

```
token = new Gson().fromJson(new String(plainTextTokenBytes, HTTP.UTF_8), ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE);
```

**Token type:**

```
ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE = new TypeToken<Quadruple<String, String, Integer, CookieManager>>() {}.getType();
```

**Quadruple class:**

```
public class Quadruple<A, B, C, D> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7513162603404965940L;

    private A first;
    private B second;
    private C third;
    private D fourth;

    public Quadruple(A first, B second, C third, D fourth) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
        this.fourth = fourth;
    }
    ...
}
```

[CookieManager developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html).
This only happens in Lollipop 5.1.0, I've tested in 5.0.2, 5.0.0 and lower and it works just fine... what could it be? I guess I'm going to open an Google issue report.
Thanks.